# Connect to SQL Server using Kerberos authentication through spark scala in GCP dataproc cluster

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, kerberos, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm able to connect to SQL server using Kerberos authentication when I run it locally but when I run the code in GCP dataproc cluster its throwing below error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed.
> GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

I'm thinking the below step is working in local but not in GCP

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", /path/krb5.conf)
```